# Determining the computer decided movein Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java

I have my tic tac toe game 90 % finished, but just can't figure out how to determine a computer generated move. I have tried multiple things, with no success.

The code I have in there now determines a random move for the computer, but can still overwrite a user inputted move and is a little buggy.

I have marked the specific spot I need help with inside the code.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
//12/14/2014
//The purpose of this program is to play a tic tac toe game against the computer
//The TicTacToe class.

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe
{
    static boolean GameOver = false ;

    public static char DrawBoard (char [] [] Board)        //DrawBoard Method
    {

        char DrawBoard = '-' ;

        System.out.println("-------------");

        for (int row = 0 ; row < 3 ; row = row + 1) 
        {
            System.out.print ("| ") ;
            for (int column = 0 ; column < 3 ; column = column + 1) 
            {
                System.out.print (Board [row] [column] + " | ") ;
                DrawBoard = Board [row] [column] ;
            }
            System.out.println () ;
            System.out.println ("-------------") ;
        }
        return (DrawBoard) ;
    }



    public static void Winner (char [] [] Board)        //Winner Method
    {
        if (Board [0] [0] == 'X' && Board [0] [1] == 'X' && Board [0] [2] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [1] [0] == 'X' && Board [1] [1] == 'X' && Board [1] [2] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [2] [0] == 'X' && Board [2] [1] == 'X' && Board [2] [2] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [0] == 'X' && Board [1] [0] == 'X' && Board [2] [0] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [1] == 'X' && Board [1] [1] == 'X' && Board [2] [1] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [2] == 'X' && Board [1] [2] == 'X' && Board [2] [2] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [0] == 'X' && Board [1] [1] == 'X' && Board [2] [2] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [2] == 'X' && Board [1] [1] == 'X' && Board [2] [0] == 'X')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have won! Congratulations.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }
    }



    public static void Loser (char [] [] Board)        //Loser Method
    {
        if (Board [0] [0] == 'O' && Board [0] [1] == 'O' && Board [0] [2] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [1] [0] == 'O' && Board [1] [1] == 'O' && Board [1] [2] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [2] [0] == 'O' && Board [2] [1] == 'O' && Board [2] [2] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [0] == 'O' && Board [1] [0] == 'O' && Board [2] [0] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [1] == 'O' && Board [1] [1] == 'O' && Board [2] [1] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [2] == 'O' && Board [1] [2] == 'O' && Board [2] [2] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [0] == 'O' && Board [1] [1] == 'O' && Board [2] [2] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }

        if (Board [0] [2] == 'O' && Board [1] [1] == 'O' && Board [2] [0] == 'O')
        {
            System.out.println ("You have lost! Better luck next time.") ;
            GameOver = true ;
        }
    }

     public static void Tie (char [] [] Board)        //Tie Method
     {
             for (int row = 0; row < 3; row = row + 1) 
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column = column + 1) 
            {
                if (Board [row] [column] == 'X' && Board [row] [column] == 'O') 
                {
                    System.out.println ("It is a tie. Cats game!") ;
                    GameOver = true ;
                }
            }  
        }
     }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    //Variable declaration
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    char [] [] Board = new char [3] [3] ;
    String MenuInput ;
    int BoardOutput ;
    int UserSpotChoice ;
    int ComputerSpotChoice = 0;
    int UserTurn = 1 ;
    int Winner = 0 ;
    Board [0] [0] = '-' ;
    Board [0] [1] = '-' ;
    Board [0] [2] = '-' ;
    Board [1] [0] = '-' ;
    Board [1] [1] = '-' ;
    Board [1] [2] = '-' ;
    Board [2] [0] = '-' ;
    Board [2] [1] = '-' ;
    Board [2] [2] = '-' ;

    //Welcome
    System.out.println ("Welcome to Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!.") ;
    System.out.println ("") ;
    System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
    System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
    System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
    MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;

    //do
    //{
    if (MenuInput.equals ("Play") || MenuInput.equals ("play")) 
    {
        while (!GameOver)
        {
        System.out.println ("\f") ;
        System.out.println (" Tic Tac Toe") ;
        BoardOutput = DrawBoard (Board) ;
        System.out.println (" 1 2 3") ;
        System.out.println (" 4 5 6") ;
        System.out.println (" 7 8 9") ;
        System.out.println ("Please enter the number you would like to move your spot to") ;
        UserSpotChoice = kbReader.nextInt () ;

        if (UserSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'X' ;
        if (UserSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'X' ;

   //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP WITH ``````````````````````````````````````````````     

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row = row + 1) 
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column = column + 1) 
            {
                if (Board [row] [column] == '-') 
                {
                    ComputerSpotChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 8 ) + 1 ;
                }  
            }
        }


        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'O' ;
        if (ComputerSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'O' ;

        Winner (Board) ;
        Loser (Board) ;
        Tie (Board) ;

        if (GameOver) System.exit (0) ;
        }
    }

 //TILL HERE ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

    else if (MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || MenuInput.equals ("instructions")) 
    {
        System.out.println ("\f") ;
        System.out.println ("You will be playing the game of Tic Tac Toe against the computer.") ;
        System.out.println ("The object of this game is to get three of your own x's or o's in a line.") ;    
        System.out.println ("You take turns placing the x's and o's and whoever gets three in a row first wins.") ;
        System.out.println ("Good Luck!") ;
        System.out.println ("") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
        MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
    }

    else if (MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || MenuInput.equals ("exit")) 
    {
        System.out.println ("Thank you for using Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!") ;
        System.exit (0) ;
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println ("Sorry, that is not a valid choice.") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
        System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
        MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
    }
    //}
    //while (!MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("Play") || !MenuInput.equals ("play") || !MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || !MenuInput.equals ("exit")) ;

    } // main method

} // TicTacToe class
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: You should use min-max algorithm, common in such games. Some links worth reading: http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: You loop over the entire game grid and if a cell contains `-` you're ignoring everything and generate a complete random number? Why do you loop over the grid if you don't care about its content?

Comment: I was just playing around with different things. I was not 100% sure on what to do. Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: Suggestions? Take a pen and paper and then think about how *you* would place your marker in the grid. If you've done that, then you can implement that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to make a few suggestions for improvements before you implement the AI. These will make your code easier to read and will help you implement the AI algorithm (which will likely involve recursion and backtracking).

1. Implement a Board class to encapsulate the state of the board (rather than using char[][]).
2. Implement a Move class to encapsulate a possible move on a board
3. Implement a Location class to encapsulate a location for a move
4. Recode your Winner/Loser methods as members of Board
5. Implement board methods to apply moves and return possible moves

Once you've done that the general form of your AI should be something like (in psuedo code):

```
public Move getMove(Board board) {
    for (Move move: board.possibleMoves()) {
        if (move will win the game)
            add move to list of good moves
        else for (Move counterMove: board.apply(move).possibleMoves()) {
            if (counterMove will NOT lose the game)
                call getMove recursively on board.apply(move).apply(counterMove);
                    add move to list of good moves only if recursive call is not null
        }
    }
    return a random move from the list of good moves, or null if it's empty
}
```

I wrote a solution to this myself to test the theory and ended up with the following for the 'bestMoves' method:

```
public List<Location> bestMoves() {
    List<Location> winningMoves = possibleMoves().stream()
            .filter(move -> apply(move).isWinFor(nextPlayer))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!winningMoves.isEmpty())
        return winningMoves;
    else
        return possibleMoves().stream()
                .filter(move -> apply(move).bestMoves().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This method returns a list of reasonable moves (ones that either win the game or don't lead to a forced win the opponent). The caller can then pick one randomly. It worked for me! Let me know if it doesn't make sense to you (e.g. if you are not used to Java 8 streams and lambdas).